# Cant destroy Cookies of Firefox in JAVA EE

Tags: java, javascript, firefox, cookies

I Have a problem with a Session Cookie, when i logout y destroy that cookie, in Chrome and IE, is going well, but i cant destroy the cookie in firefox, and if i try to go to the site again after logout, it let me in.

im using Struts 2, and i have an interceptor who read the cookies and then creates or redirectme to home page, depends if the cookie exists or not.

Also, when a push back button of firefox, the action or the interceptor is not executed.

i you need some code, i will edit the question

Comment: Why ask when you can just post the code right away?

Comment: How do you invalidate the session cookie?

Comment: i set the cookie to cero,  here is the code:                               Cookie c = new Cookie("my_cookie_name", null);
           
            c.setPath("/");
            c.setValue(null);
            c.setSecure(true);
            c.setHttpOnly(true);
            c.setMaxAge(0);
            this.servletResponse.addCookie(c);

Comment: don't put code in comments, use edit link to edit the question and post your code there.

Answer (score 0):

**In java:**

```
 private deleteCookie(String cookieName)
 {
      Cookie[] cookies = reqest.getCookies();

      if (cookies != null) {
         for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
             if (Long.valueOf(cookie.getName()).equals(cookieName)) {
                 cookie.setValue(null);
                 cookie.setMaxAge(0);
                 cookie.setPath(theSamePathAsYouUsedBeforeIfAny);
                 response.addCookie(cookie);
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

And call it as

```
deleteCookie("my_cookie_name");
```

**In javascript:**

In order to delete a cookie set the expires date to something in the past. A function that does this would be.

```
var delete_cookie = function(name) {
    document.cookie = name + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
};
```

Then to delete a cookie named my_cookie_name just do.

```
delete_cookie('my_cookie_name');
```

The problem is you are creating a new cookie instead of getting existing cookies from browser.